# Wallet won't import

Tags: wallets

So I have a wallet contract with a lot of eth in it and it is controlled by 3 eth wallets. I formatted my hdd and forgot to get type keystore folder. I was able to find the utc files that have my 3 wallet names that control my contract but that are not importing? They just say file not recognized. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Did you get it back?